# iOS: scanForPeripheralsWithServices can't find device while nRF Connect app is able to find it

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a BLE peripheral running on Raspberry Pi with [gobbledegook](https://github.com/nettlep/gobbledegook/).

In parallel, I have an iOS app working as BLE central which does a scanForPeripheralsWithServices with nil in order to detect all the devices around.

I'm able to detect a few devices, but not the one running on Raspberry Pi.
However, when scanning with the nRF Connect app on iOS, I'm able to see it.

How is that possible? (I assume that nRF Connect is also using Core Bluetooth...)

Answer (score 2):

You're likely doing something (such as using the nRF Connect app) to connect to the device, causing it to stop advertising. Most BLE platforms stop advertising when they are connected to.

Use `retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:)` to detect devices that are already connected. You must provide a list of services; there is no way to detect all devices currently connected.

Since this is on a Pi, you can also verify on that side whether the system is really currently advertising and whether it has any connections. Core Bluetooth does extensive caching, which can lead to things appearing to be happen that actually are coming out of cache. I haven't recently dug into the nRF app to verify how much it relies on the cache. I recommend also testing with [LightBlue](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/lightblue/id557428110), and testing with multiple devices simultaneously (I typically use multiple apps on iOS, Android, and Mac, and occasionally an Ubertooth, to verify what I'm seeing is true).

Note also that once you've seen an advertisement from a device once, you won't see any more during that scan unless you set `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` to true in you scan options. That flag is ignored in the background. This probably isn't the issue in this case, but often trips people up who are used to other platforms. Similarly it is almost always faster and more reliable to scan for specific services rather than `nil` unless you're building a generic BLE scanner. (Again, I doubt that's the problem in this case.)

Comment: Thank you Rob. I made another scan on a newer iPhone and I was able to detect my Rpi peripheral using my Core Bluetooth test app. Then I connected to the peripheral and was able to receive characteristic notifications. But since then, I'm not able to detect the peripheral anymore when running the test app again (note that I'm using CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey = YES.) Regarding LightBlue: I was never able to even see my Rpi peripheral listed. As to nRF Connect and caching: strangely, my Rpi peripheral is still listed even when it's not running. I'm clueless for now...

Comment: I work full time on BLE platforms, and LightBlue is our gold standard. There are a lot of things you could be doing wrong on either the app or Rpi sides. I often write small test apps on Android to check things out from a different direction. You need to make sure you're advertising correctly. There are many rules. I don't know anything about GGK, so I can't tell you if it does thing correctly out of the box or if you need to carefully configure everything. I highly recommend getting very comfortable with the BLE specs: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/

Comment: In most cases you'll spend your time in the CSS, Part A, Section 1, where it defines all the different data structures. The learning curve is unfortunately pretty steep, and BLE is not like other kinds of networking. But keep digging. It is knowable, and actually pretty well documented in the specs once you get the basics and learn where to look.

Comment: Thanks, LightBlue is a great app with a perfect documentation!